# How do I permanently add extensions to Sphinx conf.py template?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I typically use certain extensions such as `sphinxcontrib.bibtex` with every `Sphinx` documentation project, which means I need to add the extension to the `conf.py` file for each project.

```
# Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be extensions
# coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom ones.
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc', 'sphinx.ext.doctest',
'sphinx.ext.intersphinx', 'sphinx.ext.todo', 'sphinx.ext.coverage',
'sphinx.ext.pngmath', 'sphinx.ext.ifconfig', 'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
'sphinxcontrib.bibtex']
```

Is there a simple what of including these by default in `conf.py`?

Comment: For projects that generally use the same conf.py, I normally symlink it in to multiple projects and keep that under git, so I can track changes. Then all projects will update from one conf.py. Though, this is generally for PDF builds, with a general, output.pdf name, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a module containing your default settings, and then import them into your configuration file.

However, unless you are working on the project alone, it's probably better to always include the full configuration in a project so that other people working on it know they are building it with the same settings.

Another alternative might be to create a template configuration file with those settings that you could use for new projects.